# Something to Think About

Tags: untagged

[youtube]pHNyCAJXUXE[/youtube]

Answer (score 1):

Eep. I don't know what's causing it, but this guy's voice is making the hair on the back of my neck stand up...  This has happened before and generally seems to be older people talking quietly and thoughtfully.  Pretty weird.

Comment: It's 'cause you know they're about to drop a knowledge bomb. 